# Adding a String to a file name and still be able to use it

Tags: java, xml, file, copy

I have a xml file that I'm getting its full path, and pass it to a function where I add a `String` to its name. However I'm not being able to use it (the initial fullpath) after adding the string. How can it be done, that after getting the fullpath in `search(String dirName)`, and adding the string in `lk(String fullpath)`, I can still use the path which is returned by `search(String dirName)`.

```
public String search( String dirName)throws Exception{
         String fullPath = null;
         File dir = new File(dirName);
            if ( dir.isDirectory() )
            {
                String[] list = dir.list(new FilenameFilter()
                {
                    @Override
                    public boolean accept(File f, String s ) 
                    {
                        return s.endsWith(".xml");
                    }
               });

                if ( list.length > 0 )
                {
                    fullPath = dirName+list[0];
                    lockFile(fullPath);
                    return fullPath;
                }
            }

            return "";

    }

    public void lk( String fullPath) throws Exception {
          File f = new File(fullPath);
          String fileNameWithExt = f.getName();
                try {
                    File newfile =new File(fileNameWithExt+".lock");

                    if(f.renameTo(newfile)){
                        System.out.println("Rename succesful");
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("Rename failed");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
   }
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of what your xml is like in your question?

Comment: search() method is actually returning the original fullpath and not the locked path. What should search() method actually return? the file name which was found or the file name after locked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
File originalFile = new File(<file parent path>, "myxmlfile");
File cloneFile = new File(originalFile.getParent(),
         originalFile.getName()+"<anything_i_want_to_add>");
Files.copy(originalFile.toPath(),cloneFile.toPath());
//now your new file exist and you can use it
originalFile.delete();//you delete the original file
...
//after you are done with everything and you want the path back
Files.copy(cloneFile.toPath(),originalFile.toPath());
cloneFile.delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your lock method, you are calling `renameTo` method. Because of that, the original filename is now gone, and is replaced by the new filename that ends with **.lock**.

The `java.io.File` class is not a file pointer but an object to hold a filename. Using a file object that still refers to an old filename will cause an error.

To answer your question: If you want the old filename after locking, you must use a different approach in locking your file. For example, MS Access locks their **.accdb** files by creating a lockfile with the same filename as the opened **.accdb** file.

You may use this code as a reference:

```
public boolean fileIsLocked(File file) {
    File lock = new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + ".lock");
    return lock.exists();
}

public void lockFile(File file) {
    if (!fileIsLocked(file)) {
        File lock = new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + ".lock");
        lock.createNewFile();
        lock.deleteOnExit(); // unlocks file on JVM exit
    }
}

public void unlockFile(File file) {
    if (fileIsLocked(file)) {
        File lock = new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + ".lock");
        lock.delete();
    }
}
```